# GCDWebServer: Unable to open home page when using real iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, gcdwebserver

I have an old app using GCDWebUploader of GCDWebServer to upload files into the app. And I copy the implementation code into a new project.

The problem: in this new project, the home page of GCDWebServer could be opened in iOS Simulator but cannot connect in real iPhone.

**Environment:**
Xcode 12.2, iOS 14
CocoaPods

It is weird since I got a worked app already. So I did some checks:

- first, old app is worked. Means the home page could be opened.
- all devices are under same wifi.
- try to open `http://192.168.1.5/` or `http://192.168.1.5:80` in browser, safari said "Cannot open the page, because the server isn't responding", however I could ping `192.168.1.5` in terminal successfully.
- restart my iPhone
- compare info.plist between two projects

No result! Would you guys advice about what I missed, maybe some config in Xcode to allow HTTP communication or some capabilities to enable?

### What in console:

```
[DEBUG] Did open IPv4 listening socket 3
[DEBUG] Did open IPv6 listening socket 4
[INFO] GCDWebUploader started on port 80 and reachable at http://192.168.1.5/
Visit http://192.168.1.5/ in your web browser
```

### The code:

```
import GCDWebServer
import Foundation

class MyWebUploader {
    // move webuploader to outside of init func to fix app crash issue.
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    lazy var webUploader = GCDWebUploader(uploadDirectory: self.documentsPath)
    
    func initWebUploader() -> String {
        var ipAddress = String()
        
        webUploader.start()
        webUploader.allowedFileExtensions = ["mp3", "aac", "m4a", "wav"]
        if webUploader.serverURL != nil {
            // retrieve IP address from URL
            let str = webUploader.serverURL!.absoluteString
            let start = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 7)
            let end = str.index(str.endIndex, offsetBy: -1)
            let range = start..<end
            let mySubstring = str[range]
            ipAddress = String(mySubstring)
            print("Visit \(webUploader.serverURL!) in your web browser")
        } else {
            ipAddress = "No Wifi connected"
        }
        return ipAddress
    }
    
    func stopWebUploader() {
        webUploader.stop()
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is all set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is caused by the new permission in iOS 14 `to find and connect to devices on your local network`.

To fix it, we need to add following info in `info.plist`

```
    <key>NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Reason for using Bonjour that the user can understand</string>
    <key>NSBonjourServices</key>
    <array>
        <string>_http._tcp</string>
        <string>_http._udp</string>
    </array>
```

More details please see [NSNetServiceBrowser did not search with error -72008 on iOS 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65190065/nsnetservicebrowser-did-not-search-with-error-72008-on-ios-14/65190066)